# Parameter of type number appears in function as string

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to format a float as a currency string (+/- £xx.xx), from an object

```
<Autocomplete
                autoHighlight
                options={members}
                getOptionLabel={(option: memberObject) => option.name}
                renderOption={(props, option: memberObject) => (
                  <Box
                    component="li"
                    sx={{ "& > img": { mr: 2, flexShrink: 0 } }}
                    {...props}
                  >
                    {option.name} ({formatCurrencyToString(option.balance)}){" "}
                    {option.id}
                  </Box>
                )}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField
                    {...params}
                    label="Choose a member"
                    inputProps={{
                      ...params.inputProps,
                    }}
                  />
                )}
              />
```

Within the renderOption I'm using `formatCurrencyToString` on `option.balance` which comes from a `memberObject`:

```
type memberObject = {
  balance: number;
  email: string;
  extraIds: string;
  id: number;
  membershipTypeId: string;
  name: string;
  obfuscate: string;
  phone: string;
  roles: string;
  squads: string;
};
```

The functions being applied are:

```
const formatAsCurrency = (value: number) => {
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    return 0;
  }
  return value.toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
};

export const formatCurrencyToString = (value: number) => {
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    return "-";
  }
  return "£" + formatAsCurrency(value).toString();
};
```

However, it is falling over with the error "value.toFixed is not a function" because value is appearing as a string. I thought this should be protected from by the type member being a number and the parameter type of both of the functions being specified as number.

Comment: Are you sure `option.balance` is indeed a number? Even if the type says so, it might be a number at runtime. Also, to format a float as currency, you can already do that using `Number.toLocaleString()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#using_options

Comment: option.balance is a string , you can confirm by console.log(option)

Comment: You can reproduce by calling formatCurrencyToString("100")